# Docker: unix "who" command doesn't work inside container

Tags: unix, docker

I have a Docker image that has one non-root user created named builder.

The application that supposed to run inside the container uses unix `who` command.

For some reason it returns empty string inside the container:

```
builder@2dc3831c558b:~$ who
builder@2dc3831c558b:~$
```

I cannot use `whoami` because of implementation details.

(I'm using Docker 1.6.2 on Debian Jessie)

**EDIT (additional details regarding why I use "who")**:

I use the command `who` with the parameters `am i`, that is `who am i`. This suppose to return the user who first made the login. So, for example, `sudo who am i` returns `builder`, while `sudo whoami` returns `root`.

Comment: the command `who` _shows who is **logged on**_. My guess is that the container does not recognize the user as **logged on** but I'm actually as surprise as you. Did you try to run a `ssh` server, ssh in, and run a `who`?

Comment: @Auzias You were right, if I run ssh server `who` works. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The [command `who`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_who.htm) includes options like `-b`: time of last system boot.

Since all commands from a container translates into system calls to the kernel, that would not return anything container related, but docker-host related (ie the underlying host).

See also "[Difference between who and whoami commands](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156455/7490)": `whoami` prints effective username of being ran `whoami`, which is not the same as who (printing information about users who are currently logged in).

The current workarounds listed in [issue 18547](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/18547) are:

> The registry configuration is stored in the client, so something as simple as `cat ~/.docker/config.json` will give you the answer you're looking for.
>
> `docker info | grep Username` should give you this information.

But that is not the same as running the command from within a container session. `id -u` might be closer.

By default, there is no direct loggin when a container is started by the docker daemon.
As [Auzias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5321002/auzias) [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39074100/docker-unix-who-command-doesnt-work-inside-container#comment65497549_39074100), only a direct ssh connection (initiating a login session) would allow `who` to return anything. But with docker, this is generally not needed since [`docker exec`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/) (for debug purposes) exists (and spare the image maintainer to include ssh unless it is *really* needed).