# who is empty in docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Does anyone know why docker container show no output for 'who' command?

I think the container should show valid user entry when its running with docker-compose 'user' value.

docker-compose:

```
user: 95230
```

in container:

```
$ id
uid=95230 gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
$ who
$
$ whoami
whoami: cannot find name for user ID 95230
$ echo "${USER}:x:95230:201::/home/$USER:/bin/bash" >> /etc/passwd
$ whoami
mmopuru
$ who
$
```

is there way to fix 'who' with no output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker: unix "who" command doesn't work inside container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39074100/docker-unix-who-command-doesnt-work-inside-container)

Answer (score 0):

`who` command calls a function(s) in the kernel of the system, i.e., the results you get depends on the host (not the container itself). In other words, you are trying to access something you are not allowed to access, and that will not work.

## Update:

As indicated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39074100/docker-unix-who-command-doesnt-work-inside-container) answer, the following may be a workaround (I did not test it):

> The registry configuration is stored in the client, so something as simple as cat ~/.docker/config.json will give you the answer you're looking for.
>
> docker info | grep Username should give you this information.